# Postgres performance issue for JOIN on ts_vectors

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have to perform a join between two table using ts_vectors.

The "queries" table contains 2,000 records and reports > 10,000 records. Performing this query below takes 14 seconds on real data.

```
SELECT *
FROM queries 
LEFT JOIN reports ON (
         reports.query_tsvector           = queries.query_tsvector
    OR  reports.keyword_text_tsvector = queries.query_tsvector
)
```

**Optimizations**

Instead of this

```
LEFT JOIN reports ON (
      strip(to_tsvector(reports.query)        = strip(to_tsvector(queries.query)
   OR strip(to_tsvector(reports.keyword_text) = strip(to_tsvector(queries.query) 
)
```

I have created two tsvector columns and index them.
But it's not enough.

Comment: Indexes on each tsvector column of the reports table work fine for me, giving me an efficient BitmapOr plan.  Maybe you just did it wrong, you haven't provided enough information for us to know.

Comment: 14 seconds is way too expensive for just 2000 -> 10000 rows. Show required details to pin down what's going wrong. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info Do you actually need `SELECT *`? (Joining on `tsvector = tsvector` is odd to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` forces PostgreSQL to perform a nested loop join.

Rewrite it as a `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM queries
   LEFT JOIN reports
      ON reports.query_tsvector = queries.query_tsvector
UNION
SELECT *
FROM queries
   LEFT JOIN reports
      ON reports.keyword_text_tsvector = queries.query_tsvector
```

Perhaps that won't make a lot of difference (if the comparison between the `tsvector`s is the dominant cost), but at least it gives PostgreSQL the chance to use a hash join.

I guess this is an experiment, since the query doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.